# Why does count(1/null) work but count(null/null) doesn't?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I saw this example in a presentation lately. When you run a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULL)
```

You get the following error:

> Operand data type NULL is invalid for count operator.

When you run this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1/NULL)
```

You get 0 as a result, even though the division itself yields NULL as a result. Same happens if you swap the 1 and NULL.

But if you do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULL/NULL)
```

You get the same error as the first query again (the division itself is legit, yields NULL).

Can anyone explain how sql server works to give these kind of results?

Comment: The first one shouldn't result in an error to begin with, but simply return `0` (looks like a bug in SQL Server to me because it's perfectly valid SQL taking the missing FROM aside)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SQL Server certain aggregate functions such as COUNT, MIN, MAX and functions such as DATEADD require a datatype. `NULL`, on its own, does not have one so this gives you an error:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULL) -- Operand data type NULL is invalid for count operator.
```

Likewise for:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULL/NULL)
```

For `1/NULL` the datatype is INT and the value is NULL so this works:

```
SELECT COUNT(1/NULL) -- 0
```

Likewise for:

```
SELECT COUNT(CAST(NULL AS INT)) -- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a compiler error. When you go to run the batch, the T-SQL is parsed, and an error on the statements `SELECT COUNT(NULL);` and `SELECT COUNT(NULL/NULL);` is drawn at *that* time, not at execution.

If you run the batch below you'll see this quite quickly:

```
PRINT 'testing 1'

SELECT COUNT(NULL); --Error at compile
GO

PRINT 'testing 2'

SELECT COUNT(1/NULL); --Runs
GO

PRINT 'testing 3'

SELECT COUNT(NULL/NULL);  --Error at compile
GO

PRINT 'testing 4'

SELECT COUNT(0/0); --Error at run time
```

Notice that the `testing 1` and `testing 3` statement never appear.

The value `NULL`, on it's own does not have a data type. An expression where **all** sides of the expression are `NULL` will have, effectively, an unknown data type.

If you were to give the `NULL` a datatype, the issue does not happen:

```
PRINT 'testing 5'

SELECT COUNT(CONVERT(int,NULL));
GO

PRINT 'testing 6'
DECLARE @N int;

SELECT COUNT(@N);
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Also thanks for the examples of where it does work!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the data type involved. If we run the following we can see NULL alone has no datatype:

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(NULL,'BaseType')
```

Which corresponds to the error you are seeing.

We can force NULL to have a chosen data type using cast in which case the error is resolved:

```
SELECT COUNT(cast(NULL as int))
```